# SQL Query to concatenate row values based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am in need of concatenating row values based on a condition in SQL
Consider the following table
[image]

I want to concatenate `value(Column3)` where the `Column1` contains *"runs"* along with *"total"* and group by `Column2`.

My expected output is
[image]

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: If you use MSSQL Server then use `STRING_AGG()` function. If use Oracle then use `LISTAGG()` function. For more information kindly update that what database are you using?

Comment: @HoneyboyWilson I am using MSSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example solution in MSSql:

```
SELECT r1.Column2 AS 'Column1', CONCAT(r1.Column3, ',', r2.Column3) AS Result
FROM Table r1
JOIN Table r2 ON r1.Column2 = r2.Column2
WHERE r1.Column1 LIKE '%Run%' AND r2.Column1 LIKE '%Total%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select Column3, GROUP_CONCAT(Column2) ac from Tablename group by Column2
```

Comment: I am using MSSQL DBMS